# How to transform this SQL Query into Rails Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
JOIN locations 
ON locations.id = (
    SELECT id from locations 
    WHERE locations.user_id = users.id 
    ORDER BY locations.created_at 
    desc LIMIT 1
)
```

And this basically means that I have 2 models (User, Locations) in which User has_many Locations.

The result I expect is: For each user, I want to pull their last location.

How can I do that using only ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `has_one` association

```
class User
  has_one :last_location, -> { order 'created_at DESC' }, class_name: "Location"
end
```

Then you can do

```
users = User.includes(:last_location)
users.each { |u| u.last_location; ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest you could do this is by adding a scope on your `Location` model to return the most recent location.

While this doesn't give you the same SQL as you wrote manually it should provide the same results.

**location.rb**

```
scope :most_recent, -> { order(created_at: :desc).limit(1) }
```

Then something like:

```
user = User.last
user.locations.most_recent
```

This should give you this SQL output which will return the most recently created location for the user.

```
SELECT  "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."user_id" = $1  ORDER BY "locations"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Why not just `first` instead of `limit(1)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 User.where("id in (SELECT user_id from locations l 
        INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = l.user_id ORDER BY l.created_at desc LIMIT 1)")
```

Comment: Not an active record query !

Comment: Thank you, for review.It will give active record collection by using above query